# Output associated information from two tables in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, pug, sequelize.js

Assuming I have two tables: `TradeSetting` and `TradePrices`. One TradePrice may be used by multiple TradeSettings. In Express I want to list all TradeSettings with the according TradePrice and thus I use sequelize's `findAll` for both tables and pass the results to my jade view.

**My problem:**

How can I output the right price for the according TradeSetting without creating a new select for every iteration of my jade view:

```
each tradeSetting in tradeSettings
  td #{tradeSetting.Name}
  td #{tradeSetting.PriceId}
  td // the according price for this tradeSetting
```

I thought about using something like an associative array so that I could output it with `#{TradePrice[tradeSetting.PriceId]}` but I am not sure if this is possible and what I would need to do?

**My two tables look like this (simplified):**

TradeSettings (**Id**, Name, *PriceId*)

TradePrices (**Id**, Price)

**Side note:** I am not using foreign keys in my database yet, but I could add them there and adapt the models accordingly if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocess your data by iterating over your `TradeSetting`s, find the matching TradePrice for each TradeSetting and save it as a new property into every TradeSetting.

After that every TradeSetting has its correct TradePrice easily accessible as a property (just like you would access Name or PriceId).

Then you can then easily iterate over your TradeSettings and in your third `td` line (from your example) you can use `#{tradeSetting.TradePrice.Price}`

**edit:** You mentioned you're using sequelize, if its possible to set foreign keys in your db then you could make use of that as well.
If everything is set correctly try

```
TradeSetting.findAll({ include: [TradePrice])
```

then in your jade template

```
tradeSetting.get('TradePrice').get('Price')
```